# Use geom_line to draw lines for subsets of a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to draw separate lines based on part of a data frame, but when I do, lines are drawn for the points I don't want to connect.

Using geom_segment to manually draw them I get what I'm after (minus correct legend):

[image]

But when I use geom_line, which should both allow me to use my code for different graphs and also add the correct legend (I hope), the best I can do is this:

[image]

My data frame (df):

```
df <- read.table(text='Treatment           Function  Time N    Rel_abund           sd           se           ci
1      Start     "Methanogenesis" Start 3 1.983614e-04 3.839642e-05 2.216818e-05 9.538199e-05
2      Start  "Methane oxidation" Start 3 1.245265e-04 2.275417e-05 1.313712e-05 5.652448e-05
3      Start "Sulphate Reduction" Start 3 3.693332e-05 1.247878e-05 7.204626e-06 3.099900e-05
4  "1 x Flood"     "Methanogenesis"   End 3 1.673369e-04 1.043482e-05 6.024546e-06 2.592153e-05
5  "1 x Flood"  "Methane oxidation"   End 3 1.269306e-04 2.938948e-05 1.696803e-05 7.300753e-05
6  "1 x Flood" "Sulphate Reduction"   End 3 3.742168e-05 2.187629e-06 1.263028e-06 5.434372e-06
7 "3 x Floods"     "Methanogenesis"   End 3 2.135845e-04 3.762486e-05 2.172272e-05 9.346534e-05
8 "3 x Floods"  "Methane oxidation"   End 3 9.097189e-05 1.192464e-05 6.884691e-06 2.962244e-05
9 "3 x Floods" "Sulphate Reduction"   End 3 8.513220e-05 2.271764e-05 1.311603e-05 5.643374e-05')
```

And my code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Time, y=Rel_abund,col=Function))+geom_point(size=2,position=position_dodge(.1))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Rel_abund-se,ymax=Rel_abund+se),width=0.075,position=position_dodge(.1))+
  geom_line(aes(group=Function),position=position_dodge(.1))+
```

I can see what it's doing, in that it's connecting all occurrences of each Function, but when I create two new columns with NA in the appropriate rows, it still connects all of the NA occurrences.

Ultimately, I'd like a graph that looks similar to my top one, with a legend that includes the difference line types for the different treatments (1 x Flood, 3 x Floods), and that uses code that can be easily applied or modified for other datasets.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code you used to "manually draw" the first graph, using `geom_segment(...)`? I'm curious how you managed to dodge both the start and end of the segments.

Comment: @jlhoward 
    geom_segment(data=df,aes(x = 0.96, y = df$Rel_abund[1], xend = 1.96, yend = df$Rel_abund[4]),colour="#F8766D",size=.25,linetype=3)+

That's one of my commands, of which I had one for each line. If you're asking about the offsetting of the line's start and end, I specified the x coordinates and offset them by plus or minus 0.04 where appropriate (so that example moves the line 0.04 to the left). Like I said, it was a very manual approach! I hope that helps, I can show the whole thing if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know of anyway to do this other than reshaping your data for the lines. Here's the transformation I would do

```
ld<-do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Function), function(x) {
    s <- x$Time=="Start"; 
    ids <- paste(x$Function[!s], 1:sum(!s)) 
    cols <- c("Time","Rel_abund", "Function")
    suppressWarnings(rbind(
        cbind(x[s, cols], Treatment=x$Treatment[!s], id=ids), 
        cbind(x[!s, c(cols, "Treatment")], id=ids)
    ))
}))
```

Which will produce

```
    Time    Rel_abund           Function  Treatment                   id
1  Start 1.245265e-04  Methane oxidation  1 x Flood  Methane oxidation 1
2  Start 1.245265e-04  Methane oxidation 3 x Floods  Methane oxidation 2
3    End 1.269306e-04  Methane oxidation  1 x Flood  Methane oxidation 1
4    End 9.097189e-05  Methane oxidation 3 x Floods  Methane oxidation 2
5  Start 1.983614e-04     Methanogenesis  1 x Flood     Methanogenesis 1
6  Start 1.983614e-04     Methanogenesis 3 x Floods     Methanogenesis 2
7    End 1.673369e-04     Methanogenesis  1 x Flood     Methanogenesis 1
8    End 2.135845e-04     Methanogenesis 3 x Floods     Methanogenesis 2
9  Start 3.693332e-05 Sulphate Reduction  1 x Flood Sulphate Reduction 1
10 Start 3.693332e-05 Sulphate Reduction 3 x Floods Sulphate Reduction 2
11   End 3.742168e-05 Sulphate Reduction  1 x Flood Sulphate Reduction 1
12   End 8.513220e-05 Sulphate Reduction 3 x Floods Sulphate Reduction 2
```

So we've replicated the Start value for each Function/Treatment combination. Then we kept both End values. We also update the Treatment for the Start values so we can style based on that. Finally we added an ID so qqplot will know which start/end points to connect. It may not be the prettiest transformation but it gets the job done.

Now we can draw the plot with

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Time, y=Rel_abund, col=Function))+
    geom_point(size=2,position=position_dodge(.1))+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Rel_abund-se, ymax=Rel_abund+se), 
        width=0.075, position=position_dodge(.1))+
    geom_line(data=ld, aes(group=id, lty=Treatment),
        position=position_dodge(.1)
)
```

Notice that we use the original data.frame for the first new commands, and specify our special dataset just for the `geom_line()`. And that will give us

[image]

which is pretty close to your first picture.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that uses `geom_segment(...)` and does not require reshaping the dataset, although I must admit it's a bit of a hack.

```
df$Start <- merge(df,df[df$Time=="Start",c(3,5)],by="Time")$Rel_abund.y
df$Time  <- factor(df$Time,levels=c("Start","End"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Time, y=Rel_abund,col=Function))+
  geom_point(size=2,position=position_dodge(.1))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Rel_abund-se,ymax=Rel_abund+se),width=0.075,position=position_dodge(.1))+
  geom_segment(data=df[df$Time!="Start",], 
               aes(x=1, xend=2+(as.numeric(Function)-2)*0.04, y=Start, yend=Rel_abund, color=Function , linetype=Treatment),
               position=position_dodge(0.1))
```

[image]

So here we add an extra column, `Start`, to `df` which contains the starting value of `Rel_abund` - in other words we replicate `df[df$Time=="Start",]$Rel_abund` for each value of `Function`. Using `merge(...)` to do this just guarantees that the values are assigned proerly for different values of `Function`. From there it's straightforward to used `geom_segment(...)`, except for one thing: you want to dodge the x-values.

The problem with dodging `geom_segment(...)` is that `position_dodge(...)` is only applied to the `x` aesthetic, not `xend`. So the code above hacks that by adding `0.04*(as.numeric(Function)-2)` to `xend`.